# What is the problem with this code...Image window stays a few second and quits so quickly....My code here

Tags: python, opencv

What is the problem with this code?

Image window stays a few second and quits so quickly.

**Here the code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=np.zeros((512,512,3),np.uint8)

while True:

    cv2.imshow("Gray",img)
    if cv2.wiatKey(20) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: @ Anamul Akash three answers have been provided to your question. Please take the time to check what better works for you and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

*cv2.waitKey* takes as argument delay in ms (1 ms = 0.001 second), so *cv2.waitKey(20)* means wait for 0.02 second.

Comment: but when i run it ,it shows      cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'wiatKey

Comment: Now I noticed that you have spelling error: it should be `wait` not `wiat`

Answer (score 0):

The function `cv2.waitKey()` takes an argument in milliseconds. Passing `20` as an argument causes it to wait 20 milliseconds for a keystroke and then quit.

**However** if `0` is passed, it waits indefinitely for a keystroke, so the following should fix it:

```
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Alternatively you can increase the time for the key stroke to something in order of seconds:

```
cv.waitKey(20000)
```

, which will wait for 20 seconds.

Comment: I tried. when i run  it shows that  AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'wiatKey'

Comment: That's because you have a typo in your code. The function is called ```waitKey``` not ```wiatKey```

Answer (score 0):

- **1**

As a first thing, you mispell `cv.waitKey` with `cv.wiatKey` which results in the error *cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'wiatKey* you're experiencing.

- **2**

As a second thing, if you would like to use your logic to display an image use the following working code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=np.zeros((512,512,3),np.uint8)

while True:

    cv2.imshow("Gray",img)

    if cv2.waitkey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

- **3**

As last point, in order to keep things simple, you don't need to write *all that code* to display an image. Just use the following simple instruction lines that will take care of displaying an image, and wait for a key press for closing the window.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=np.zeros((512,512,3),np.uint8)
cv2.imshow("Image",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)      
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: yeah it works and .i did a mistake in  spelling my code

Comment: @AnamulAkash three answers have been provided to your question. Please take the time to check what better works for you and mark it as accepted.